# When does a torsion $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module have unique maximal submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module with cardinality powers of $p$ and consisting of $p^n$-torsion points for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

In other words, for any $m \in M$, we get $p^n \cdot m=0$.

> I want to know when $M$ can be cyclic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module ?

Since $M$ is finitely generated, it would be cyclic if we show $M$ has an unique maximal submodule.

---

Let us arrange the elements of $M$ with an indexing $\{m_1,m_2,\cdots, m_i, \cdots \}$ in the sense that $m_i$ has order $p^i$.

- If we assume $pm_i=m_{i+1}$, then I think $M=\left\langle m_1 \right\rangle$. In that case $M$ is cyclic.

Do we have other way to show that $M$ is cyclic or $M$ has unique submodule which is maximal ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it clear to you that the only (up to isomorphism) cyclic $\mathbb Z_p$-modules are $\mathbb Z_p$ itself and all $\mathbb Z/p^k$? Is it not obvious which ones of these have $p^n$-torsion? -- Or alternatively, you are aware of the structure of finitely generated torsion modules over a PID?

Comment: Also, I do not understand how your "arranging" of the elements of $M$ is supposed to work. In general, a nonzero module will contain more than one element of a given order, so we cannot have $pm_i = m_{i+1}$ for all $i$ and at the same time assume that the set of all $m_i$ exhausts $M$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I am assuming $pm_i=m_{i+1}$.

Comment: I can read that. But as I said, then we cannot have $M = \{m_1, m_2, ... \}$ except in trivial cases. --- I really do not know what you are asking for. A module is cyclic if it is cyclic, there are a few equivalent definitions of that. As said in my first comment, in the case at hand the cyclic modules are known as explicitly as one could hope for, certainly more explicit than "assuming" some kind of ordering. Are you given some module via some definition which does not make it immediately clear whether it is one from the list in my first comment? Then you should say how it *is* given.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, yes I assuming too much.  I understand $M$ is cyclic iff $M \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.  But can you please explain your 1st comment where you said $M$ is isomorphic all $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, when I said "arrange", I don't mean a sequence. I wrote this for simplicity. Indeed, there are more than one element of exact order $p$ or $p^2$, so on. I am representing all $p$-torsion points by $m_1$, all $p^2$-torsion points by $m_2$, so on.  But it seems the answer can not be true in general even if the number of $m_i$'s  are equal to that of $m_{i+1}$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in coments, it is not clear what exactly you are asking. Maybe the following reminder helps:

For a unital commutative ring $R$, every cyclic $R$-module is isomorphic to $R/I$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$.

The only ideals of $\mathbb Z_p$ are $(0)$ and all $(p^n)$ for $n \in \{0,1,2,...\}$.

Hence up to isomorphism, the only cyclic $\mathbb Z_p$-modules are $\mathbb Z_p$ itself and $\mathbb Z_p/(p^n)$ for $n \in \{0,1,2,...\}$.
It is well-known that $\mathbb Z_p/(p^n) \simeq \mathbb Z/(p^n)$.

If you have a $\mathbb Z_p$-module $M$ which is torsion and has finite cardinality ($p^c$, say), then in particular it is finitely generated, and hence by the structure theory of f.g. torsion modules over PIDs (or an easier version thereof in this case of a DVR), it is a direct sum of cyclic modules. So here:

$$M \simeq \bigoplus_{n \ge 0} (\mathbb Z/p^n)^{i_n} \qquad \qquad (*)$$

where $(\mathbb Z/(p^n))^{i_n}$ is short notation for $\underbrace{\mathbb Z/(p^n) \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb Z/(p^n)}_{i_n \text{ times}}$, and only finitely many $i_n$ are $\neq 0$. Actually, for $M$ to have cardinality $p^c$, we need $\prod_{n \ge 0} n \cdot i_n = c$.

Obviously the cyclic ones among these are the ones where $i_n=1$ for $n=c$ and $i_n=0$ for all $n \neq c$.

Or in other words, if the module has cardinality $p^c$ and is cyclic, it must be $\simeq \mathbb Z/p^c$. So: *If we know the module has cardinality $p^c$*, then for it to be cyclic it suffices to show, for example, that it has an element of order $p^c$ (which is nearly trivially equivalent to being cyclic, if you think about it).

As regards torsion, *if we know that $M$ has exact torsion $p^t$* (i.e. $p^t \cdot m=0$ for all $m$ but there is $m \in M$ with $p^{t-1} \cdot m \neq 0$), then in $(*)$  this only imposes the restriction that $i_t \neq 0$ and $i_{t+1}=i_{t+2}= ... =0$. As said above, such module is cyclic iff $i_t=1$ and all other $i_n=0$ i.e. iff $M =\simeq \mathbb Z/(p^t)$ i.e. iff it has cardinality $p^t$. (It would suffice to show its cardinality is $\le p^t$.)

As said in comments, I find it hard to imagine how you are given a module $M$ for which you can decide *at all* whether it is cyclic, but without that decision being kind of immediate via any of the criteria above.

Comment: thanks. I think this is enough to make everything clear.